# Find deprecated api version?

Tags: android, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm using camera in my app but the eclipse shows msg as "The type Camera is deprecated". So I'd like to know in which api the camera is deprecated?

Comment: and btw, eclipse too is kind of deprecated for android development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search on the Android Docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

> This class was deprecated in API level 21. We recommend using the new
>   android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications.

Comment: Thanks for reply, is there any feature in eclipse to find this.

Comment: @user2551070 Everything you can do with Android Studio, you can do with Eclipse, as well...

Answer (score 0):

The camera api is deprecated as of API 21. This means for devices running up to KitKat 4.4 (API 19) you can use Camera. For devices Lollipop 5.0 and above (API 21+) you can use Camera2 instead.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html